# I can not get information with "DialogflowApp.getUser" method

Tags: node.js, firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ApiAiApp

I'd like to obtain an access token on Dialogflow by referring to the above official website, but the execution result of `DialogflowApp.getUser()` will be null.

Account linking is set up and on the client side it is certified with a Google Account.
`AssistantToAgentDebug.assistantToAgentJson.user` on the DEBUG tab of DialogFlow Simulator contains a value.

Also, I can get an access token by referring `req.body.originalRequest.data.user.accessToken` variable on the request body.

I'd like to obtain user information with `DialogflowApp.getUser()`,
Is there a mistake in the definition below?

*Using the Fullfilment, the logic is described in index.js.

*index.js

```
'use strict';

const App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.testMethod = (req, res) => {

  // result is null
  const app = new App({req, res});
  let user = app.getUser();
  console.log('User is ' + user);

  // Access token can be acquired
  let accessToken = req.body.originalRequest.data.user.accessToken;
  console.log('accessToken is ' + accessToken);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': 'success!', 'displayText': 'success!' }));
};
```

*package.json

```
{
  "name": "testMethod",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the call to the constructor expect the parameters to be named `request` and `response`. So you should write the line as

```
const app = new App({request:req, response:res});
```

Comment: Glad it helped you out! Upvoting and/or accepting an answer is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getUser().accesToken like this:

```
let accestoken = app.getUser().accessToken;
```

Comment: They're reporting that `getUser()` is returning null.