# Get UserId GoogleActions

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to get the userId in Firebase for my Google user but, apparently it's undefined

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
 ReferenceError: userId is not defined
    at IncomingMessage.resp.on (/user_code/index.js:73:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

This is my code

```
    const REQUEST_PERMISSION_ACTION = 'request_permission';
    const userUID = app.getUser().userId;
    const userName = app.getUserName().displayName;
    console.log(userUID, 'USERRRRRRID');
```

What can I do to get the userId?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749476/i-can-not-get-information-with-dialogflowapp-getuser-method/47752302

Comment: I tried to get my token but apparently it's Null (TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of null)

Comment: I was referring to Prisoner's post about `const app = new App({request:req, response:res});` Try adding more of your code to your post so we can help better if that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried too but it ask me to define req and res. i will post more of my code.

Comment: `req` & `res` are the parameters that you define where you first get the request, in your case it seems to be `resp`?

Comment: resp looks working, but req... ok i putted almost all my code now... sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is bigger part of my code

```
function processV1Request (request, response) {
  let action = request.body.result.action; // https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters
  let parameters = request.body.result.parameters; // https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters
  let inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts; // https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts
  let requestSource = (request.body.originalRequest) ? request.body.originalRequest.source : undefined;
  const googleAssistantRequest = 'google'; // Constant to identify Google Assistant requests
  const app = new DialogflowApp({request: request, response: response});
  // Create handlers for Dialogflow actions as well as a 'default' handler
  const actionHandlers = {
    // The default welcome intent has been matched, welcome the user (https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#default_welcome_intent)
    'input.welcome': () => {
    sendGoogleResponse(' Bonjour, Que puis je faire pour vous ?');
    },
    'input.what': () => {

    const http = require('http');
    const https = require('https');
    https.get('https://bnpparibas-api.openbankproject.com/obp/v3.0.0/my/banks/bnpparibas.07.fr/accounts/cbf874f8-9eb1-4fdf-899c-54b8c5e7c2c8/account', (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    const app = new ActionsSdkApp({request: request, response: response});



  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;

  });
```

Comment: If you place `const userUID = app.getUser().userId;` before your http call it should work?

Comment: Just for future reference - you shouldn't post followup info as an answer, you can just edit your original question. And Bart should post that as an answer so you can accept it as an answer and others can upvote it. Hiding in a comment, others may not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the assistant to guide the user to grant permission for your app to get this information.

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#askForPermission)

Comment: No you don't. That's only if you want the username or some other information. The userId can be obtained at anytime without any additional permissions.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, only when getting other information.